# How to use React$Element in FlowType?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Here is my simple `<ListItem />` react component. I want it to have a **marker** prop that only allows two types of components, either an `<Icon />` or a `<Label />`.

```
import React, { Element } from 'react';

import { Icon } from '../Icon';
import { Label } from '../Label';

type Props = {
  marker?: Element<Icon> | Element<Label>,
};

const ListItem = ({ marker }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>{marker}</div>
  );
};

export default ListItem;
```

How shall I represent the simple use case in FlowType? I tried the following but all of them seem to not work. That is why I wonder, how to properly use **React$Element** to exactly allow two particular types of react components?

```
type Marker = Icon | Label;

type Props = {
  marker?: Element<Marker>,
};
```

---

```
type Props = {
  marker?: Element<Icon> | Element<Label>,
};
```

Comment: You can't use `Element` this way unfortunately, since the parameter here is the prop interface to the components. Specifically, within flow internals, the type `React$Element<Config>`'s  `Config` parameter is `$Diff<Props, DefaultProps>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that you are attempting will work in Flow versions 0.53.0 and later with a minor change: the type parameter of `Element` is a type expression position, but `Icon` and `Label` are values. You need to use `typeof` to refer to their types:

```
type Props = {
  marker?: Element<typeof Icon> | Element<typeof Label>,
};
```

Flow's type definitions for React changed substantially in v0.53.0, including a change that switched `Element`'s type parameter from a `Config` to a `React$ElementType` which makes it much easier to talk about elements created by specific components.

### Hack for Flow v0.52.0 and earlier

@Lewis Chung pointed out in a comment that the `Config` parameter to `Element` before Flow v0.53.0 is created by the expression `$Diff<Props, DefaultProps>`. If `Icon` and `Label` have distinct props types then you can distinguish elements created by those components in older versions of Flow using a hack like this:

```
type Props = {
  marker?: Element<IconProps> | Element<LabelProps>,
};
```

That assumes that `Icon` and `Label` do not have default props. If they do then you need to expand the type to produce the appropriate diffs:

```
type Props = {
  marker?:
    | Element<$Diff<IconProps, IconDefaultProps>>
    | Element<$Diff<LabelProps, LabelDefaultProps>>,
};
```

Comment: Just figured that out recently that it became possible. Thanks for the write-up.